Reproduce MacOS DNS dialog in SwiftUI
I'd like to create a window identical to the one used to configure DNS servers in MacOS:

Specifically, the dialog should:

have +/- buttons to add delete rows
row selectable on single click
content selected and editable on double click

In another question, @soundflix suggested to use a Table() with a custom view in each cell but the appearance and behavior is quite different than the DNS dialog.
Does anyone know which SwiftUI feature is used to make the DNS dialog? Any other tips?
Thanks
struct EditView: View {
    @State private var mEditList: [EditItem] = [
        EditItem(id: 1, original: "bobo", replacement: "freddy"),
        EditItem(id: 2, original: "abcde", replacement: "gateway")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("OCR is not a perfect science and makes mistakes. Please edit the list below to correct them.")
            
            Table($mEditList) {
                TableColumn(Text("##")) { item in
                    Text("\(item.id)")
                }
                .width(50)
                
                TableColumn("Replace") { $item in
                    EditableTextView(text: $item.original)
                }
                
                TableColumn("With...") { $item in
                    EditableTextView(text: $item.replacement)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditableTextView: View {
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if isEditing {
            HStack {
                TextField("Text", text: $text)
                Button("Done") {
                    isEditing = false
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
        } else {
            Text("\(text)")
                .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                    isEditing = true
                }
        }
    }
}


I don't think there is a native component for this in SwiftUI, but it's not hard to create something similar yourself. In a VStack, put a List with .plain style, and an HStack of buttons below that. Each row of the List would be a TextField, allowing you to edit the text. If you have multiple editable columns, you can just put multiple TextFields in an HStack.
The following example is largely based on rob mayoff's answer here.
struct DNSEntry: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var ip: String
}

struct DNSList: View {
    @State var dnsEntries = [DNSEntry]()
    @State var selection: UUID?
    @FocusState var focused: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            List($dnsEntries, editActions: .all, selection: $selection) { $entry in
                TextField("", text: $entry.ip)
                    .focused($focused, equals: entry.id)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ListButton(imageName: "plus") {
                    let newEntry = DNSEntry(ip: "")
                    dnsEntries.append(newEntry)
                    focused = newEntry.id
                    selection = newEntry.id
                }
                Divider()
                ListButton(imageName: "minus") {
                    if let selection, let index = dnsEntries.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == selection }) {
                        self.selection = nil
                        focused = nil
                        Task {
                            dnsEntries.remove(at: index)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .disabled(selection == nil)
                Divider()
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 20)
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color(NSColor.controlColor))
        }
    }
}

struct ListButton: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    }
}


You can also just wrap a NSViewRepresentable. See here for how this is done in AppKit.
